# event.target on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, firefox3.5

```
 var x = event.target||event.srcElement;
 document.getElementById(x.id).style.left =  200 + "px" ;
 document.getElementById(x.id).style.top  =  100 + "px" ;
```

Works fine on Google Chrome and IE but not on Firefox. Tried it on Google. Google says  `event.srcElement` (works on IE but not on Firefox) so I have added  `event.target` but still not working. Is there anymore changes I need to do to work on Firefox? By the way I'm using 3.5 version of Firefox.

```
   function up()
       {
            dragok = false;
            document.onmousemove = null;
            var x = event.target||event.srcElement;
            document.getElementById(x.id).style.left= 200 + "px" ;
            document.getElementById(x.id).style.top= 100 + "px" ;
       }
```

Please help me to make it work on Firefox

Comment: could you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/ example of the complete code which "does not work" ?

Comment: Could you please show more code (ideally a JSFiddle demo)? BTW, there's no need to look for `x`'s `id` and then look back for particular element by the `id`, you can just work with `x.style.left`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Make sure you define `event` as a formal parameter to the handler.

`IE` defines it globally, and `Chrome` defines it both in both places, so it works either way, but `Firefox` only defines it as a function parameter.

```
function up( e ) {
    //       ^-----------------------------------------------------+
    if( !e ) e = window.event; // <---needed this --- and this ->--+

    dragok = false;
    document.onmousemove = null;
    var x = e.target||e.srcElement; // <--- and these
    document.getElementById(x.id).style.left= 200 + "px" ;
    document.getElementById(x.id).style.top= 100 + "px" ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using Jquery. For example to get the id of a element you can use:

```
var x = $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution to work in Firefox browser too. When start `keydown` action then its set the `event` property to global variable like this.

```
 var keyEvent=null;
```

Assign that `event` property to `keyEvent` and `.item` is target element.

```
  $(document).on("keydown",'.item', function(e){ 

                keyEvent=e;                                    

        },this))
```

then.Use `keyEvent` in your code.

```
     function up( e ) {
           if( !e ) e = keyEvent;  
             dragok = false;
             document.onmousemove = null;
             var x = e.target||e.srcElement; 
             document.getElementById(x.id).style.left= 200 + "px" ;
             document.getElementById(x.id).style.top= 100 + "px" ;
         }
```

**Note**: Don't try to set the `event` property to global variable of `window`.