# Event.target issue with Firefox 6

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events

In Firefox 6 I tried to get the target element on which the event occurred, but it does not show any element and it shows undefined in alert. Tried to debug it using the Firebug tool and found the attribute "target" missing for the event object. Can anyone help me out? I do have the code below:

```
function getSource(event)
{
    if(!event) 
    { 
        field = window.event.srcElement;
       alert(field);
    }
    else
    {
        field = event.target; 
        alert(field) //Getting undefined in FF6
    }
}
```

Edited Portion:

```
document.onkeypress = getSource;
document.onmouseup = getSource;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what **type** of event is this (and what's the `target` you are expecting)? Does it work on all other browsers?

Comment: It is a click event the target can be either, button, textbox, etc

Comment: can you show the HTML snippet where the handler `getSource()` is registered? Or perhaps, the entire HTML is that's possible.

Comment: Without any more information or code, I'm going to have to say this probably isn't a problem in FF6. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target , https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets , http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-interface

Comment: See the edited portion. @rfausak: I tried the same code in firefox 3 and am getting what I want, but only in firefox6 I get this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [event.target not working on Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457260/event-target-not-working-on-firefox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below

```
function getSource(e)
{
     if(!e)
        e = window.event;
     field = evt.srcElement || evt.target;
     alert(field);
     return true;
 }
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Test this in Fx 6:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('d0').onclick = showTarget;
}

function showTarget(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  alert(target.tagName);
}

</script>

<div id="d0">
  <p>click on me</p>
</div>
```

It should alert "P".

Answer (score 0):

As also explained in the similar question, change the function to this:

```
function getSource(evt)
{
    if(!evt) 
        evt = window.event;
    if (evt) {
        field = evt.srcElement || evt.target;
        alert(field);
        return true;
    }
    alert("event not found");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Nobody understand what I am saying, I don't get the "target" attribute in the firebug tool itself, how would you expect your code to work in firefox 6?

Comment: The problem with your code was that when `event` wasn't defined you always too `srcElement` from `window.event` - most likely, you need `window.event.target` in FF6

Comment: So how come you marked this as Accepted? If working, please let us know what you've done. :)

Comment: The code you have given is correct but the explanation given is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSource(ev) {
  var el=(ev=ev||window.event).target||ev.srcElement;
  alert(el+" "+el.tagName);
}
```