# non-jQuery solution for Firefox event target

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to learn Javascript before I learn jQuery so I can get the foundation down before moving up.

To learn, I've made a simple guessing game that works in Chrome & Safari, but not Firefox. (I guess that is why people use jQuery!).

I adjusted the code based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457260/event-target-not-working-on-firefox). But it is still not working in Firefox. Here's the relevant code. Any ideas?

```
function reportAnswer(e) {
  if(!e) e = window.event;
  questionNumber++;
  document.getElementById("myCount").innerHTML = (questionNumber + 1);
  var x = e.target || e.srcElement;
  checkAnswer();
}

function checkAnswer() {
  var thisAnswer = questionDatabase[currentQuestion].answer;
  if(event.target.id == thisAnswer) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = ("YES! </br>" + questionDatabase[currentQuestion].photo);
    score++;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = ("<img src=http://philly.barstoolsports.com/files/2012/11/family-feud-x2.png width='370' height='370'>");
  }
}
```

Comment: "TypeError: e is underdefined"

Comment: Webkit browsers usually handle attributes with/without Quotes.

you are missing Quotes for the 'src' attribute in the Else Block

Answer (score 1):

Your `checkAnswer` function uses the nonstandard global `window.event`.  You want to do two things:

1. Add an `event` or `e` argument to it like @thesystem suggests.
2. Make sure to pass that argument in from whatever your event handler is.