# Issue with Firefox: event.target

Tags: javascript, firefox

I use the script below to replace some diacritical marks from legacy to standard form. Works fine in all browsers, except Firefox; where it does not work at all. I assume the problem is from event.target, but I am just beginning with javascript and lack the know how for fixing this.

Found this (posible?) solution to my problem, but don't know how to adapt it for my script: [event.target not working on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457260/event-target-not-working-on-firefox)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function inlocuire_diacritice (form) {
var form = event.target;
var i, l;
for (i = 0, l = form.elements.length; i < l; i += 1) {
if (form.elements[i].type === 'text') {
  form.elements[i].value = form.elements[i].value.replace(/Ş/g, 'Ș');
  form.elements[i].value = form.elements[i].value.replace(/ş/g, 'ș');
  form.elements[i].value = form.elements[i].value.replace(/Ţ/g, 'Ț');
  form.elements[i].value = form.elements[i].value.replace(/ţ/g, 'ț');
}
}
return true; 
}
```

EDIT: I call the function from inside another function:

```
function validate(form) {
//form validation script
inlocuire_diacritice (form);
}
```

And this is called on form submit:

```
<form action="whatever" name="whatever" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
```

Comment: How do you call this function? `event` is "alive" only within an eventhandler function (in IE only). If this is an evenhandler, `form` argument probably is the missing `event` in FF...

Comment: ...and your function var is `form` but youre creating a new var named `form` inside it.

Comment: @BatuZet To be exact, `form` is re-assigned only. Arguments are declared before the body of the function is executed, hence the "double" `var` is omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form action="whatever" name="whatever" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(event, this)">...</form>
```

And the function :

```
function inlocuire_diacritice (ev, form) {
    // form is a reference to the form element already
    // if you need event.target, use ev.target
    // this refers to the element to which this event is attached
                :
}
```

Actually in FF (or in any modern browser) you don't need to pass arguments when invoking the function, in the function declaration you need to include one argument, which represents `event`. `this` in eventhandler refers to the element, to which the event is attached.

Please read about [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to see, how the listeners should actually be attached to elements.

Comment: You mean function inlocuire_diacritice (event, form) {  or function inlocuire_diacritice (ev, form) { ?

Comment: Literal `event` must be passed, the argument name in the function declaration doesn't matter, use what you wish (except keywords ofcourse).