# event is not defined javascript firefox (json)

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

### can any body tell me why my code error on firefox?

**HTML:**

```
Size : <select class="size" id="size<?php echo $dat_women->id; ?>" name="size" onchange="change_size(<?php echo $dat_women->id; ?>)">
```

**JS:**

```
function change_size(id_product){
    var size  = document.getElementById(event.target.id).value;
    $.ajax({
        dataType:"json",
        url: site_url + "main/add_cart/" + id_product + "/" + size,
        success:function(data){ 
            window.location.assign("cart");
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('Anda belum memilih ukuran');
        }
    });
};
```

**Error:**

> event is not defined

Comment: And what is the error you're getting?

Comment: @JonathanM "event is not defined".

Comment: The real error, line number included...

Comment: @abc123 It is a real error message (FF).

Comment: what's the HTML on the client? not the server side?

Comment: I think you might need to modify the call: `onchange="change_size(this,<?php echo $dat_women->id; ?>)"` and then in the function definition do `function change_size(element, id_product)`. That way you can refer to the `element`.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23011402/1169519).

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the element as a parameter to the function call:

In your HTML:

```
onchange="change_size(this,<?php echo $dat_women->id; ?>)"
```

and in your function defnition:

```
function change_size(element, id_product)
```

then you can get the `size` like this:

```
var size = element.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/mazuObvO22QVpNqp4zXi?p=preview)

**HTML:**

```
<select class="size" id="size2" name="size" onchange="change_size(this, 2)">
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
function change_size(id_product){
    var size  = $(this).value;
    $.ajax({
        dataType:"json",
        url: site_url + "main/add_cart/" + id_product + "/" + size,
        success:function(data){ 
            window.location.assign("cart");
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('Anda belum memilih ukuran');
        }
    });
};
```