# event object not defined only with Firefox (IE and Chrome works)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

```
<a class="lnk" href="#" onclick="showItem();">
    <span data-id="27">TEST</span>
</a>

function showItem()
{
    var itid = event.target.dataset.id;
    alert(itid);
}
```

If you try [this jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/tek5yqdd/1/) you can see that with IE (11) and Chrome the event object is correctly evaluated, but with Firefox (32.0) you get an error (ReferenceError : event is not defined)

It's a bug of Firefox or a different event object lifecycle in IE and Chrome ?
However since in IE and Chrome it's working I think it's a problem.
About a workaround ?

p.s: in jsfiddle, only with firefox, code selection still having problem (after some run you cannot select code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should pass `event` as an argument to the function:

```
<a class="lnk" href="#" onclick="showItem(event);">
    <span data-id="27">TEST</span>
</a>

function showItem(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    var itid = e.target.dataset.id;
    alert(itid);
}
```

Accessing it as a global variable is an IE feature that Chrome copied, but I don't think it's standard Javascript.

Comment: ok works, but part of the question is : why in IE and Chrome works without passing the event ? they implicitly pass it ?

Comment: They have a global variable that gets set to the current event.

Comment: ok, the answer at that part of the question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457260/event-target-not-working-on-firefox

Comment: Right. This answer won't work in IE. That question shows the correct code for all browsers.