# Getting Event Id in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
\$Title.on('blur',function(){

            //on blur fire the event
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);
            if (\$Title.val()) {
              typingTimer = setTimeout(doneInput ,doneTypingInterval);
             \$eventId =  event.target.id;
              console.log(event.target.id);
            }

        });
```

When this event is fired a request is sent to DB, now i want if the request was successful i will display a message to the user, i have many DIV one the same page with different ID and different event say like on change event, Now i want to be able to know which particular Div return success so i used `even.target.id` which returns the ID as i desire, now when i test code it works as expected in chrome and in IE, but when i test on firefox ReferenceError: event id not define. `$eventId` is a global variable so i try to set the value to `$eventId ="";` to see if this can work but still it doesn't work, inicially i define it like this `$eventId;` any help on this, why this don't work on firefox. Thanks for any help

Comment: Please follow this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457260/event-target-not-working-on-firefox.

Comment: This code is not syntaxically valid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with firefox, In firefox, you have to receive event object in your event handler like `\$Title.on('blur',function(event)` this solves my problem