# e.target.href not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, reactjs, events

e.target.href does not work in firefox. This only works in chrome. I tried following question's solution ([event.target not working on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457260/event-target-not-working-on-firefox)) but still not working on firefox. Do i have to add something more?

**app.js**

```
showModal(e) {
    if (!e) {
      e = window.event;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    const event = e.target || e.srcElement;
    const url = event.href;
    console.log('url', url, event.href);
    const redirectTo = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    this.setState({ show: true });
    this.context.router.transitionTo(redirectTo);
  } 

<Nav
  showModal={(e) => this.showModal(e)}
  hideModal={() => this.hideModal()}
  show={this.state.show}
  onHide={() => this.hideModal()}
/>
```

**Nav.js**

```
<button
  className="btn btn-default"
  onClick={(e) => props.showModal(e)}
>
 <Link to={{ pathname: '/signup' }}>
   {props.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'nav.registration.text' }) }
 </Link>
</button>
```

Comment: What does "not work in firefox" mean? What do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `getAttribute()`

> ```
>    const tgt = e.target || e.srcElement;
>    const url = tgt.getAttribute('href');
>    console.log('url', url, tgt);
> ```

```js
showModal(e) {
    if (!e) {
      e = window.event;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    const tgt = e.target || e.srcElement;
    const url = tgt.getAttribute('href');
    console.log('url', url, tgt);
    const redirectTo = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    this.setState({ show: true });
    this.context.router.transitionTo(redirectTo);
  }
```

Comment: I tried that too. I got null in firefox but it works in chrome and also i dont need to manipulate string.

Comment: There's more than one way to skin a cat--try: `var xHref = tgt.getAttributeNode("href").value`